# Generar pdf con MySQL, node y ejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, pdf, ejs

estoy realizando un proyecto web y quiero generar un pdf que se llene con datos de mySQL, actualmente ya tengo la conexión y me arroja los datos lo comprobe con un res.render() a una vista.... quiero saber como pasar esos datos a un PDF

adjunto mi codigo:

Mi controlador donde tengo la conexion con DB y la consulta SQL

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.proyectosHome =  (req, res) => {  
// Parámetros de conexión a la base de datos.
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database : 'tasker'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("select * from proyectos", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    res.render('index.ejs',
    {
      datos :result
    });

  })
});
}
```

asi tengo la vista donde tengo una etiqueta `<a>` que al darle clic genere un PDF con los datos de `select * from proyectos`

INDEX.EJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <% for( let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++ ) { %>
    <%- datos[i].nombre %>
    <% } %>

    <a href="#">Generar PDF</a>
</body>
</html>
```